# zxing project on android

Tags: android, eclipse, import, zxing

Many weeks ago,I tried to work on a mini project on Android OS 
requires ZXING, I followed several tutorials on this web site and on other 
Example: [tuto1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zxing), and many tags and tutorials here [tuto2](http://knol.google.com/k/alec-go/modifying-the-android-barcode-scanner/2vd5zn6va2fqd/2), [tuto3](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GettingStarted) ... But I failed each time. I can't import the android project into eclipse IDE to compile it **with my code**  "not via Intent zxing APK-and my program like this example :

```
private Button.OnClickListener btScanListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");


        try {
          startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SCAN);
       } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
         Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Barcode Scanner not intaled ", 2000).show();
       }
    }
};



public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent intent) {
    if (REQUEST_SCAN == reqCode) {
        if (RESULT_OK == resCode) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Succès : " + contents, 2000).show();
        } else if (RESULT_CANCELED == resCode) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scan annulé", 2000).show();
        }
    }
}`
```

".
I feel disappointed, frustrated and sad. 
I still have errors after importing the project.
I tried both versions 1.5 and 1.6 zxing 
I tried to import the project c: \ ZXing-1.6 \ android, and an other new project with c: \ ZXing-1.6 \ zxing-1.6 \ android,I cheked out SVN: ttp: / / zxing.googlecode.com / svn / trunk / zxing-read-only with tortoiseSVN and reproduce the same work, but unfortunately without results! 
I really fed up with myself  ... 
Please help me to solve this problem.how can I import the project and compile it correctly in my own project?

1 - I use Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium

2 - Eclipse IDE for Java EE Web Developers. Version: Helios Service Release 2 Build id: 20110218-0911

What is the effective and sure method to run this, otherwise if there is a video or a guide details or 
someone who already done it previously
I would really appreciate it if someone would help me out

Answer (score 1):

Zxing is a very nice project, unfortunately integrating it can sometimes be a pain. I followed the steps below. If not refer to [blog](http://mcondev.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/zxing-1-7-for-android-on-eclipse/).

- Checkout the zxing sources from zxing.org
- Create a Android project on your eclipse
- Delete main.xml
- Right click on “src” directory and hit import. Browse to the following directories in the order mentioned. As you add them for import one by one, ensure that you have the src directory in the edit field of the import wizard. And that you select only the “com” directory on the left directory tree. Do not select src.
- core
- android-integration
- android
- Ensure that your android sdk version is 9, anything lesser and androidmanifest.xml will cry.
- Strings.xml in one of the languages will crib, just put a / before the ‘ character

For a download of a sample import, [this](http://mcondev.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/zxing-1-7-for-android-on-eclipse/) will get you started immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You have not said anything about your problem. You also appear pretty confused about whether you are integrating via Intent. You are integrating via Intent here, and this is the right way to do it, not as you are. http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: <<You have not said anything about your problem.>>

I can't import all Zxing source code into eclipse IDE to make some modification and compile it with my code my code source
->new android project ->import zxing all android libs and core ->make some change on zxing classes ->adding some personal Activity ->compile the project when i import the source code of zxing and core folder I had errors like, several package not found, the incorrect name of the class ...

Comment: This still doesn't give specifics, but I am guessing you are trying to compile code for JavaME and RIM which of course won't work unless you have those SDKs installed.

Comment: No i am working with android ,i am newbie but this is not my first project on Android ,for exemple res/values/strings.xml: Use %s as a placeholder for the product ID\, and %f for format the eclipse IDE show this message "Multiple annotations found at this line: - error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false"attribute? - error: Unexpected end tag string" !! the same error in all the strings.xml like values-fr,values-ru

Comment: Yes, that's my point. You are building an Android app, but you seem to be including all the project code, which includes code for completely different platforms. I don't know, since you're still not being very clear about the errors! why not just post it in your original question?

Comment: thank you.Can u please tell me how to solve this problem because i want my application to be stand alone. i don't want to install BarcodeScanner.apk separately in the device. the first step.I imported only the project title android "C:\zebra\crossing\ZXing-1.6 \ android, then I link the core file "configure build path-> source link> folder, I set the path "C:\zebra crossing\ZXing-1.6\core", I have checked src folder. after importing and linking the source my project have uncountable errors in strings.xml name of packages and classes.I hope that you understande my problem sorry for my english.

Comment: Seriously, you are going to get much farther on StackOverflow if you *actually post the error you are getting*!! It sounds like you are not going to be able to build your own standalone app; it requires more knowledge of Android. So you should try Intents.

Comment: i'm so greatfull for your help.

Comment: .i arrived to solve my problem using Ant appache, only one error in res\values\strings.xml: <stringname="preferences_custom_product_search_summary">Use %s as a placeholder for the product ID , and %f for format</string> this line cause me this in eclipse view problems:
ERROR Description Resource Path Location Type error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute? strings.xml /CaptureActivity/res/values line 96 Android AAPT Probl